# VS2012 CodedUI Recording: How to handle MouseWheel?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, automated-tests, integration-testing, coded-ui-tests, mousewheel

I have recorded a set of actions on a UI with the integrated Coded UI Test Recorder. It works kind of nice.. actually, right now I am going through the code and adding some polling for .Enabled and recently found the .TryGetClickablePoint which seems to be really useful. So it looks like recording is a breeze now (with those few polls to be added to get the timing right).

One thing that is a typical use case of the GUI is using the mouse wheel (for interacting with a zoomable image like in google maps). It seems like those are not captured.

I could manually generate those events, but would be far off from reproducing the actual behavior during recording with manually guessing the extent of the scrolling.

Is there some integrated way?
Would I have to capture the events myself with some external/selfmade tool to at least get an idea of how many ticks I made?

Answer (score 1):

For stuff like this I'd recommend using the API directly for your test. You can use the Mouse.MoveScrollWheel method for this. You might have to experiment a little to get the number of ticks right.

Comment: I know that is possible. I wanted to record user input without having to manipulate it afterwards. Finally, we went with a macro recorder for ease of creation of tests - even though many features got lost that way.